# What is the difference between Sfardic and Ashkenazic calculations for the last time to eat chametz?

Tags: time, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, zemanim, ashkenazi, chametz-leaven

My community's *luach* (calendar) has 2 separate times for the last time to eat chametz on Erev Pesach: 10:09 for Ashkenazim, and 10:13 for Sephardim.

How are these times calculated according to the different traditions?

Comment: I'm unsure about difference for Ashkenaz vs. Sefarad. But, I'm curious if these times don't correspond to the typical 2 times I see in many of my calendars - such as the one on www.myzmanim.com. The earlier time is for *Magen Avraham* and the later time is according to *Gra / Ba'al Hatanya*.

Answer (score 1):

Not the amount of difference you mentiond but I believe it is similiar.
Check last time for chametz section [here](http://www.yeshiva.org.il/midrash/4652)

> כל ההבדל בין האשכנזים לספרדים הוא, שאנחנו מחשבים את היום מעמוד השחר עד 20 דקות אחרי השקיעה, ואילו האשכנזים מחשבים את היום בחשבון אחר, ולדעת הגאון מוילנא היום מתחיל מהנץ החמה ועד השקיעה, ולפי"ז יוצא זמן ארבע שעות זמניות בחשבון אחר.

*All the difference between Ashkenaz and Sefarad is, we[Sefarad] calculate the day from Dawn until 20 minutes after sunset, while Ashkenaz use a different clculation, according to the Vilna Ga'on the day starts at sunrise, hence different times for 4 Sha'ot Zemaniot.*

As DanF mentioned, 'tis proabably the normal dissputes between Sha'a Zemanit calculation ([Dive here](http://www.yeshiva.org.il/wiki/index.php?title=%D7%96%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%99_%D7%94%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9D)).

Comment: I believe that it is. I don't know where @Scimonster lives. Regardless, I am surprised that the difference this time of year would be 4 minutes, unless he lives very far north.